# How do you create an input form as shown in the attached picture using QML?

Tags: forms, layout, input, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to create an input form that looks similar to the attached picture. Is this the 'standard' way to do this with QML? I've tried using layouts but can't get it to look like this.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1


Window {
    id: window
    title: qsTr("Test")
    width: Screen.width / 8
    height: Screen.height / 4
    minimumWidth: 300
    minimumHeight: 300

    visible: true
    color: "#ff0000"

    Rectangle  {
        id: rootrect
        color: "#000000"

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0

        Column  {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            spacing: 10

            Rectangle  {
                color: "#000000"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                height: 40;
                width: parent.width

                Label {
                    text: "Username"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    anchors.left: parent.left

                }
                TextField {
                    x: .3*parent.width
                    width: .65*parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                }
            }

            Rectangle  {
                color: "#000000"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                height: 40;
                width: parent.width

                Label {
                    text: "Password"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                }
                TextField {
                    x: .3*parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    width: .65*parent.width
                }
            }
        }                       // Column


        Rectangle  {
            color: "#000000"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 40;
            width: parent.width-20;
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: rootrect.bottom;
            anchors.margins: 10

            Button {
                text: "Exit"
                x: .25*parent.width - width/2
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                onClicked: {
                    window.close();
                }
            }                   // Button

            Button {
                text: "Save"
                x: .75*parent.width - width/2
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                onClicked: {
                }
            }                   // Button
        }                           // Rectangle
    }                               // Rectangle
}  

                             // Window
```

What I'm after:

[image]

Comment: That can be easily done with `Layout`. `GridLayout` in your case will be good. Looking at `Layout.fillWidth: true` which affects nothing in your case I guess you've already tried to do that. What was a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple template code how it can be done with layouts:

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 600
    visible: true

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        columns: 2

        Label { text: "Username" }
        TextField { Layout.fillWidth: true }

        Label { text: "Password" }
        TextField { Layout.fillWidth: true }

        Item { Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.columnSpan: 2 }

        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            Layout.columnSpan: 2

            RowLayout {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Button { text: "Cancel" }
                Button { text: "OK" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. I had no idea about using Items this way. Thanks

Comment: Why a `RowLayout` inside an `Item` and not just a `RowLayout` ?

Comment: Sure, @GrecKo it have to be removed. I've just copied it from one of my forms where it stylized as a panel with different color.